# How to read edf data in Python 3

Tags: python, time-series, european-data-format, mne-python

How can I read edf data using Python? I want to analyze data of a edf file, but I cannot read it using [pyEDFlib](https://pyedflib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It threw the error `OSError: The file is discontinous and cannot be read` and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get help with your problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I assume that your data are biological time-series like EEG, is this correct? If so, you can use the MNE library.

You have to install it first. Since it is not a standard library, take a look [here](https://martinos.org/mne/dev/getting_started.html). Then, you can use the [`read_raw_edf()`](https://martinos.org/mne/dev/generated/mne.io.read_raw_edf.html) method.

For example:

```
import mne
file = "my_path\\my_file.edf"
data = mne.io.read_raw_edf(file)
raw_data = data.get_data()
# you can get the metadata included in the file and a list of all channels:
info = data.info
channels = data.ch_names
```

See documentation in the links above for other properties of the data object

Comment: Yes. Your assume is right. The data I used is EEG data. Thank you very much. I have read the data successfully according to your solutions with adding the parameter 'preload=True' in code 'data = mne.io.read_raw_edf(file)' at the same time.

Comment: @Mindy I'm glad to hear my response was helpful.

Comment: What if it's not EEG and I don't want to use MNE for dependency reasons?

Comment: @dcxst  I would ask a new question, link to this one and specify why this isn't sufficient for you

Answer (score 0):

Another way to read an edf file --> array using pyedflib (if you don't want to use mne for dependency reasons):

```
 import pyedflib
 def edf_to_arr(edf_path):
    f = pyedflib.EdfReader(edf_path)
    n = f.signals_in_file
    signal_labels = f.getSignalLabels()
    sigbufs = np.zeros((n, f.getNSamples()[0]))
    for i in np.arange(n):
        sigbufs[i, :] = f.readSignal(i)
    
    return sigbufs
```

There's more documentation here: [pyedflib docs](https://pyedflib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)